# How to do positional indexing on a pandas series with multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a series

```
s

card  city
c1    t1      0.500000
      t2      0.250000
      t3      0.250000
c2    t2      0.666667
      t1      0.333333
Name: city, dtype: float64
```

I want to get the top (or n-th) `city` entry for each `card`. I essentially want something of `s.iloc[:,n]` type i.e., a way to do positional indexing into a pandas series with multi-index. I am using `pandas-1.3.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby.head`:

```
s.groupby(level='card').head(1)

card  city
c1    t1      0.500000
c2    t2      0.666667
Name: city2, dtype: float64
```

---

To get the `n-th` entry per group, `group` first and then use `iloc` in each group. For instance, to get the 2nd entry for each card:

```
n = 1
(s.groupby(level='card', group_keys=False)
  .apply(lambda g: g.iloc[n:n+1]))

card  city
c1    t2      0.250000
c2    t1      0.333333
Name: city2, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it will work. However, does it mean that .iloc or any positional indexing scheme cannot work on a series with multi-index?

Comment: `iloc` can only  index values by positions and doesn't have the concept of multiindex signature. If you use `iloc`, you'll still have to leverage `groupby` and in each group use `iloc[0]` which will have the same effect as `head(1)`.

Comment: Thanks. For the same question as above, how to get the n-th city for each card. I am editing my question accordingly.

Comment: Please do not edit your question, it can make the answer invalid

Comment: apologies, I already edited it prior to getting your comment. However, I saw your edited answer and it is appropriate for me here. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure no worries. In general if you have a new question extending the original one, it's better to ask a new question since the change can invalidate the original answer which some people may still find useful. But I think it's fine here, since it's a minor change.